# Comparison of Adams-Bashforth and Runge-Kutta methods of order 4

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods

I have a system of ODE, that must to solve with numerical methods. I solve it by Adams_Bashforth with order4 and Runge-Kutta with order4 methods. Do you know with same length step which methods answers exactly?

Comment: Can you please clarify your question? In general, both methods should give you an answer with error $O(h^4)$. The difference in the method comes in the fact that different methods must be applied in different situations, depending on what system you are solving. If it is a sufficiently well-behaved one, both methods should work equally well. (Although for Adams-Bashforth you would need to obtain some initial solution values, in order to initialize it).

Comment: @Aahz Yes I have a sufficiently well-behaved problem and my system is nonlinear.So you mean those answer is approximately same, yes?

Comment: Well, yes, they should. 4'th order is 4'th order, after all. If you are implementing the code yourself, then keep in mind, that the initial values for Adams-Bashforth must be with the same (or better) order of precision, as the method itself.

Comment: @Aahz,Thanks a lot. For example can I use $RK_4$ for Adams-Bashforth 4?

Comment: Yes, I think so.

Answer (score -3):

Runge-Kutta is a fixed step solver but Adams is a variable step solver. You can't compare them with the same step size because in Adams method you define max. and min. step size with relative tolerance. You don't define a single step size like 0.01 as in Runge Kutta method. Obviously, variable step solvers give smoother results but the computation time also increases.

You can find a comparison of different methods here: [Matlab Alghorithms](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ode113.html#bti6pdv-40)

**Edit:** This answer is about variable step Adams-Bashforth-Moulton solver in Matlab. I don't know its fixed step version.

Comment: as I read in Adams-Bashforth method we have fix step, too.

Comment: Yeah, Adams-Bashforth is a multistep method, not a variable-step one.

Comment: @user169140 I never used its fixed step version sorry.

Comment: @Aahz In Matlab it is variable step, I edited the answer accordingly.

Comment: This is a rather inaccurate statement. The original formulation by Adams, Bashforth, and Moulton do have this multistep method working for fixed step sizes, and the modification for it to be able to handle variable steps by Nordsieck and others came way, way later.